# Worldwide weather maps database

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

I am searching for a database (a free one would be great) that would give me, for any chosen rectangular area on earth, historic data about pressure, sea water temperature, wind (including both speed and direction) and in general as much weather-related information as possible.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: You could create one using the ISD data: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/

Comment: @BarryCarter - I took a look at the data in your link to see if it would help me.  I need historical weather data back to 2010.  Your regular weather information (i.e., temperature, feels like, humidity, dew, sunrise, sunset, etc.).  From what I saw, it looks like there is no data for 2010.  Maybe I'm not looking in the right place.  Do you have any information that might help me?

Comment: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2010/ should be the data for 2010. ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-lite/isd-lite-format.txt should explain the format.